# Java: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, classpath

To compile my java app, I use from terminal:

```
javac -cp commons-digester-2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar:lucene-core-3.0.3.jar CollectionIndexer.java
```

To run the app I use:

```
java -classpath commons-digester-2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar:lucene-core-3.0.3.jar CollectionIndexer
```

However I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: commons-digester-2/1/commons-digester-2/1/jar:lucene-core-3/0/3/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: commons-digester-2.1.commons-digester-2.1.jar:lucene-core-3.0.3.jar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

I guess I'm defining correctly the classpath.. or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `-cp` instead of `classpath`. Also add the current directory to the classpath.

```
$ java -cp .:commons-digester-2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar:lucene-core-3.0.3.jar CollectionIndexer
```

or

```
$ export CLASSPATH=.:commons-digester-2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar:lucene-core-3.0.3.jar
$ java CollectionIndexer
```

If on Windows, use backslashes and a semi-colon separator:

```
java -cp .;commons-digester-2.1\commons-digester-2.1.jar;lucene-core-3.0.3.jar CollectionIndexer
```

Comment: @Patrick see my update. What java version are you using? I assume you are on Unix?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to set the classpath first with

SET CLASSPATH command and then execute your program as

java CollectionIndexer.

Comment: exactly the same issue. set CLASSPATH=commons-digester-2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar:lucene-core-3.0.3.jar and then: java CollectionIndexer